How do I draw a filled polygon in monogame?
I am experimenting with procedural animation in Monogame. I was able to create this lizard out of circles and then used parametric equations to draw vertices along the circles in order to make the outline seen below. What I am trying to figure out is how to actually fill in the area within the vertices with color or textures. Not sure if I bit off more than I could chew doing this in monogame and this would be easier with Unity or another game engine. Any help is appreciated.

using Microsoft.Xna.Framework.Graphics;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;

namespace SimpleGame
{
    public class Lizard : Creature
{
    private List<Vector2> allPositions;
    private List<int> allRadii;
    private Vector2 direction;
    private Vector2 legOneTarget;
    private Vector2 legOneFoot;
    private Vector2 legOneJoint;
    private float legMoveThreshold = 20f; 

    private Texture2D legTexture;
    private int legRadius = 10;

        public Lizard(GraphicsDevice graphicsDevice, Vector2 startPosition)
        : base(200f)
    {
       
        allPositions = new List<Vector2>();
        allRadii = new List<int>();
        var LizardCol = Color.Transparent;

        
        List<Vector2> headPos = new List<Vector2> { startPosition };
            List<Texture2D> headTextures = new List<Texture2D> { CreateCircleTexture(graphicsDevice, 20, LizardCol) };
            List<int> headRadii = new List<int> { 20 };
        var head = new BodyPart(headPos, headTextures, headRadii, "Head");
        bodyParts.Add(head);
        allPositions.AddRange(headPos);
        allRadii.AddRange(headRadii);

        
        List<Vector2> bodyPositions = new List<Vector2>
        {
            startPosition - new Vector2(0, 25),
            startPosition - new Vector2(0, 45),
            startPosition - new Vector2(0, 70),
            startPosition - new Vector2(0, 95),
        };
        List<Texture2D> bodyTextures = new List<Texture2D>
        {
            CreateCircleTexture(graphicsDevice, 20, LizardCol),
            CreateCircleTexture(graphicsDevice, 25, LizardCol),
            CreateCircleTexture(graphicsDevice, 25, LizardCol),
            CreateCircleTexture(graphicsDevice, 25, LizardCol),
        };
        List<int> bodyRadii = new List<int> { 20, 25, 25, 25 };
        var body = new BodyPart(bodyPositions, bodyTextures, bodyRadii, "Body") { PreviousPart = head };
        bodyParts.Add(body);
        allPositions.AddRange(bodyPositions);
        allRadii.AddRange(bodyRadii);

        
        List<Vector2> tailPositions = new List<Vector2>
        {
            startPosition - new Vector2(0, 75),
            startPosition - new Vector2(0, 100),
            startPosition - new Vector2(0, 125),
            startPosition - new Vector2(0, 150),
            startPosition - new Vector2(0, 175),
            startPosition - new Vector2(0, 200),
            startPosition - new Vector2(0, 225),
            startPosition - new Vector2(0, 230),
            startPosition - new Vector2(0, 240),
            startPosition - new Vector2(0, 250),
        };
        List<Texture2D> tailTextures = new List<Texture2D>
        {
            CreateCircleTexture(graphicsDevice, 20, LizardCol),
            CreateCircleTexture(graphicsDevice, 18, LizardCol),
            CreateCircleTexture(graphicsDevice, 16, LizardCol),
            CreateCircleTexture(graphicsDevice, 14, LizardCol),
            CreateCircleTexture(graphicsDevice, 12, LizardCol),
            CreateCircleTexture(graphicsDevice, 10, LizardCol),
            CreateCircleTexture(graphicsDevice, 8, LizardCol),
            CreateCircleTexture(graphicsDevice, 6, LizardCol),
            CreateCircleTexture(graphicsDevice, 4, LizardCol),
            CreateCircleTexture(graphicsDevice, 2, LizardCol),
        };
        List<int> tailRadii = new List<int> { 20, 18, 16, 14, 12, 10, 8, 6, 4, 2 };
        var tail = new BodyPart(tailPositions, tailTextures, tailRadii, "Tail") { PreviousPart = body };
        bodyParts.Add(tail);
        allPositions.AddRange(tailPositions);
        allRadii.AddRange(tailRadii);

        
        float initialBodyAngle = (float)Math.Atan2(allPositions[0].Y - allPositions[1].Y, allPositions[0].X - allPositions[1].X);
        float legAngleOffset = MathHelper.PiOver4; 
        float legDistance = 60; 

        legOneTarget = allPositions[1] + new Vector2((float)Math.Cos(initialBodyAngle + legAngleOffset), (float)Math.Sin(initialBodyAngle + legAngleOffset)) * legDistance;
        legOneFoot = legOneTarget;
        legOneJoint = allPositions[1] + (legOneFoot - allPositions[1]) * 0.6f; 

        this.legTexture = CreateCircleTexture(graphicsDevice, legRadius, Color.Green);

        direction = Vector2.UnitX; 
    }

 

     public override void Update(GameTime gameTime, Vector2 targetPosition)
        {
            if (float.IsNaN(targetPosition.X) || float.IsNaN(targetPosition.Y))
            {
                targetPosition = HeadPosition;
            }

            direction = targetPosition - HeadPosition;
            direction.Normalize();

            allPositions[0] += direction * CircleSpeed * (float)gameTime.ElapsedGameTime.TotalSeconds;

            // Update the head rotation angle
            UpdateHeadRotation(direction);

            // Update body positions
            UpdatePositions(MathHelper.ToRadians(40f)); // Adjust the angle as needed
            UpdateLegOne(); // Update leg position
        }

        private void UpdatePositions(float maxAngleChange)
        {
            float interpolationSpeed = 0.1f; 

            for (int i = 1; i < allPositions.Count; i++)
            {
                Vector2 direction;
                if (i == 1)
                {
                    
                    float currentAngle = (float)Math.Atan2(allPositions[i].Y - allPositions[0].Y, allPositions[i].X - allPositions[0].X);
                    
                    float desiredAngle = (float)Math.Atan2(this.direction.Y, this.direction.X) + MathHelper.Pi;
                    
                    float newAngle = LerpAngle(currentAngle, desiredAngle, interpolationSpeed);

                    
                    Vector2 desiredPosition = allPositions[0] + new Vector2((float)Math.Cos(newAngle), (float)Math.Sin(newAngle)) * allRadii[i - 1];

                    
                    allPositions[i] = desiredPosition;
                }
                else
                {
                    direction = allPositions[i - 1] - allPositions[i];

                    float length = direction.Length();
                    if (length < float.Epsilon)
                    {
                        length = 1;
                    }

                    direction.Normalize();
                    float angle = (float)Math.Atan2(direction.Y, direction.X);

                    if (i > 1)
                    {
                        float prevAngle = (float)Math.Atan2(allPositions[i - 2].Y - allPositions[i - 1].Y, allPositions[i - 2].X - allPositions[i - 1].X);
                        float angleDiff = MathHelper.WrapAngle(angle - prevAngle);

                        if (Math.Abs(angleDiff) > maxAngleChange)
                        {
                            angle = prevAngle + Math.Sign(angleDiff) * maxAngleChange;
                        }
                    }

                    direction = new Vector2((float)Math.Cos(angle), (float)Math.Sin(angle));
                    allPositions[i] = allPositions[i - 1] - direction * allRadii[i - 1];
                }
            }

            
            int index = 0;
            foreach (var part in bodyParts)
            {
                for (int i = 0; i < part.Positions.Count; i++, index++)
                {
                    part.Positions[i] = allPositions[index];
                }
            }
        }

    private float LerpAngle(float from, float to, float t)
    {
        float difference = MathHelper.WrapAngle(to - from);
        if (difference < -MathHelper.Pi)
        {
            difference += MathHelper.TwoPi;
        }
        else if (difference > MathHelper.Pi)
        {
            difference -= MathHelper.TwoPi;
        }

        return from + difference * t;
    }

    private void UpdateLegOne()
    {
        Vector2 anchor = allPositions[1];
        Vector2 toTarget = legOneTarget - legOneFoot;

        if (toTarget.Length() > legMoveThreshold)
        {
            legOneFoot = legOneTarget;
        }

        
        float bodyAngle = (float)Math.Atan2(allPositions[0].Y - allPositions[1].Y, allPositions[0].X - allPositions[1].X);
        float legAngleOffset = MathHelper.PiOver4; 
        float legDistance = 50;
        legOneTarget = anchor + new Vector2((float)Math.Cos(bodyAngle + legAngleOffset), (float)Math.Sin(bodyAngle + legAngleOffset)) * legDistance;

        
        Vector2 toFoot = legOneFoot - anchor;
        float footAngle = (float)Math.Atan2(toFoot.Y, toFoot.X);

        
        float jointAngle = footAngle + MathHelper.PiOver4; 
        float jointDistance = 30f; 

        
        legOneJoint = anchor + new Vector2((float)Math.Cos(jointAngle), (float)Math.Sin(jointAngle)) * jointDistance;

        
        legOneFoot = Vector2.Lerp(legOneFoot, legOneTarget, 0.1f); 
    }




        public void DrawOutline(SpriteBatch spriteBatch)
        {
            Vector2 headPosition = allPositions[0];
            int headRadius = allRadii[0];
            float angle = (float)Math.Atan2(direction.Y, direction.X);

            
            Vector2 frontPoint = GetPointOnCircumference(headPosition, headRadius, angle);
            Vector2 leftPoint = GetPointOnCircumference(headPosition, headRadius, angle - MathHelper.PiOver2);
            Vector2 rightPoint = GetPointOnCircumference(headPosition, headRadius, angle + MathHelper.PiOver2);
            Vector2 leftMidPoint = GetPointOnCircumference(headPosition, headRadius, angle - MathHelper.PiOver4);
            Vector2 rightMidPoint = GetPointOnCircumference(headPosition, headRadius, angle + MathHelper.PiOver4);

            
            Vector2[] allPoints = new Vector2[(allPositions.Count - 1) * 2 + 7]; 

            
            allPoints[0] = frontPoint;
            allPoints[1] = leftMidPoint;
            allPoints[2] = leftPoint;

           
            int index = 3;
            for (int i = 1; i < allPositions.Count; i++)
            {
                float partAngle = (float)Math.Atan2(allPositions[i - 1].Y - allPositions[i].Y, allPositions[i - 1].X - allPositions[i].X);
                allPoints[index++] = GetPointOnCircumference(allPositions[i], allRadii[i], partAngle - MathHelper.PiOver2);
            }

            
            Vector2 tailTipPosition = allPositions[allPositions.Count - 1];
            int tailTipRadius = allRadii[allRadii.Count - 1];
            float tailAngle = (float)Math.Atan2(allPositions[allPositions.Count - 2].Y - tailTipPosition.Y, allPositions[allPositions.Count - 2].X - tailTipPosition.X);
            Vector2 tailTip = GetPointOnCircumference(tailTipPosition, tailTipRadius, tailAngle + MathHelper.Pi);
            allPoints[index++] = tailTip;

            
            for (int i = allPositions.Count - 1; i > 0; i--)
            {
                float partAngle = (float)Math.Atan2(allPositions[i - 1].Y - allPositions[i].Y, allPositions[i - 1].X - allPositions[i].X);
                allPoints[index++] = GetPointOnCircumference(allPositions[i], allRadii[i], partAngle + MathHelper.PiOver2);
            }

           
            allPoints[index++] = rightPoint;
            allPoints[index++] = rightMidPoint;
            allPoints[index] = frontPoint;

            Texture2D pointTexture = CreateCircleTexture(spriteBatch.GraphicsDevice, 2, Color.Red);

            
            foreach (var point in allPoints)
            {
                spriteBatch.Draw(pointTexture, point, Color.White);
            }

           
            for (int i = 0; i < allPoints.Length - 1; i++)
            {
                if (allPoints[i] != Vector2.Zero && allPoints[i + 1] != Vector2.Zero) 
                {
                    DrawLine(spriteBatch, pointTexture, allPoints[i], allPoints[i + 1], Color.White, 1);
                }
            }

            
            if (allPoints[allPoints.Length - 1] != Vector2.Zero && allPoints[0] != Vector2.Zero) 
            {
                DrawLine(spriteBatch, pointTexture, allPoints[allPoints.Length - 1], allPoints[0], Color.White, 1);
            }

            
            spriteBatch.Draw(legTexture, legOneJoint - new Vector2(legRadius), Color.White);
            spriteBatch.Draw(legTexture, legOneFoot - new Vector2(legRadius), Color.White);
        }

        private Vector2 GetPointOnCircumference(Vector2 center, int radius, float angle)
        {
            return new Vector2(
                center.X + radius * (float)Math.Cos(angle),
                center.Y + radius * (float)Math.Sin(angle)
            );
        }

    

private void DrawLine(SpriteBatch spriteBatch, Texture2D texture, Vector2 start, Vector2 end, Color color, int thickness)
{
    Vector2 edge = end - start;
    float angle = (float)Math.Atan2(edge.Y, edge.X);

    spriteBatch.Draw(texture,
        new Rectangle((int)start.X, (int)start.Y, (int)edge.Length(), thickness),
        null,
        color,
        angle,
        new Vector2(0, 0.5f),
        SpriteEffects.None,
        0);
}
    }
}


This question is similar to: MonoGame / XNA Draw Polygon in Spritebatch. If you believe it’s different, please edit the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
